# Перекрыть метод toString()

Tags: java

Создать перечисление "Месяц". Необходимо определять в конструкторе и сохранять количество дней. Добавить методы получения предыдущего и следующего месяца, а также функцию, которая возвращает сезон для каждого месяца. Предусмотреть вывод месяцев на русском языке. Создать статическую функцию вывода данных обо всех месяца путем перекрытия метода `toString()`. Протестировать перечисление в функции `main()` тестового класса.
Помогите перекрыть метод `toString()`.

```
enum Month12 {
    JANUARY(31), FEBRUARY(28), MARCH(31), APRIL(30), MAY(31), JUNE(30), JULY(31), AUGEST(
            31), SEPTEMBER(30), OCTOBER(31), NOVEMBER(30), DECEMBER(31);

private Integer days;

private Month12(Integer days) {
    this.days = days;
}

public Integer getDays() {
    return days;
}

public String toString() {
    switch (this) {
    case JANUARY:
        return "Январь";
    case FEBRUARY:
        return "Февраль";
    case MARCH:
        return "Март";
    case APRIL:
        return "Апрель";
    case MAY:
        return "Май";
    case JUNE:
        return "Июнь";
    case JULY:
        return "Июль";
    case AUGEST:
        return "Август";
    case SEPTEMBER:
        return "Сентябрь";
    case OCTOBER:
        return "Октябрь";
    case NOVEMBER:
        return "Ноябрь";
    case DECEMBER:
        return "Декабрь";
    }
    return "not month";

}

Month12 next() {
    Month12 a = values()[(ordinal() + 1) % values().length];
    return a;
}

Month12 before() {
    Month12 a = values()[(ordinal() - 1 + 12) % values().length];
    return a;
}

public String season() {
    switch (this) {
    case JANUARY:
    case FEBRUARY:
    case DECEMBER:
        return "Зима";
    case MARCH:
    case APRIL:
    case MAY:
        return "Весна";
    case JUNE:
    case JULY:
    case AUGEST:
        return "Лето";
    case SEPTEMBER:
    case OCTOBER:
    case NOVEMBER:
        return "Осень";
    default:
        return "not month";
    }
}

}

public class Month {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Month12 a = Month12.JANUARY;
    System.out.println("Введенный месяц: " + a);
    System.out.println(a.next());
    System.out.println(a.before());
    System.out.println(a.season());

}

}
```

Comment: А что не так в приведённом вами коде?

Comment: Я не знаю как создать статическую функцию вывода данных обо всех месяцах путем перекрытия метода toString()

Comment: Статическую? Невозможно, `toString()` не является статической функцией. /thread

Comment: А не проще в энаме не только кол-во дней держать, а ещё и название месяца? Тогда и toString() перезаписать проще будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте Eclipse. Создаете класс, в свободное место Ctrl+Space - появится автозаполнение. Выберите там toString() и создастся перезаписанный метод, даже с указанием аннотации.

Малость переписал энам от скуки...

```
    package main;

public enum Month12 {
    JANUARY(31, "Январь", "Зима"),
    FEBRUARY(28, "Февраль", "Зима"),
    MARCH(31, "Март", "Весна"),
    APRIL(30, "Апрель", "Весна"),
    MAY(31, "Май", "Весна"),
    JUNE(30, "Июнь", "Лето"),
    JULY(31, "Июль", "Лето"),
    AUGEST(31, "Август", "Лето"),
    SEPTEMBER(30, "Сентябрь", "Осень"),
    OCTOBER(31, "Октябрь", "Осень"),
    NOVEMBER(30, "Ноябрь", "Осень"),
    DECEMBER(31, "Декабрь", "Зима");

    private final int _days;
    private final String _name;
    private final String _season;

    Month12(int days, String name, String season) {
        _days = days;
        _name = name;
        _season = season;
    }

    public int getDays() {
        return _days;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return _name;
    }

    public String getSeason() {
        return _season;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName() + "(" + getDays() + " в месяце, сезон - " + getSeason() + ")";
    }

    public Month12 getNext() {
        int next = ordinal() + 1;
        return next >= values().length ? JANUARY : values()[next];
    }

    public Month12 getPrevious() {
        int next = ordinal() - 1;
        return next < 0 ? DECEMBER : values()[next];
    }
}
```

И ещё... У элементов энама ВСЕ методы являются как бы статичными (при указании для элемента).

Comment: Евгений, спасибо)

Comment: Спасибо на кнопку тыкают и ответ принимают))

Comment: Сезон лучше выделить в отдельный Enum

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте

```
public String toString() {
    //..
}
```

на:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    //..
}
```

Comment: Как уже сказал VladD, нельзя создать статическую функцию toString.